# Cloth doesn't move during simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

I've create a scene with a cloth pin to an empty but when I want to move the empty while the sim is running, the cloth doesn't follow in real time.

I've try to [follow this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cZAJ5aKwGo) but it seams to not work on the lastest version of blender.

Video of the problem : https://streamable.com/pqvqqo

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Try to make Empty As Parent of a vertex : [image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: it works but you have to hit play (spacebar) in order to launch the simulation. Also put your cloth a bit closer to the empty

Comment: Sorry moonboots but it's not working.. I ran the simulation many time before posting my question. As you can see on the two images on this post, simulation is running and the cloth doesn't follow the empty correctly and moreover, it's keep the last wrong movements in cache when the timeline restart again..

Comment: it works for me in 2.82 and 2.91 alpha

Comment: I'm working on Blender 2.90.0 :)
I've edited my first post with a video of the issue

Comment: if you've baked your simulation you need to delete the bake

Comment: @moonboots From screen of "Shape" panel with grey "PinGroup" it seems you have a big chance you hit the nail head :)

Comment: oh ok I'm going to try an answer then

Answer (score 0):

You've probably baked your cloth simulation, so whatever you do with your empty, nothing happens. We couldn't see it with the shared file probably because it doesn't have access to the cache files. So simply *Delete Bake*:

[image]

Also I wonder if hooking is the good solution, it looks buggy, maybe simply parent to the empty?

Comment: Hello ! I've tried it.. Unfortunaly as you can see on the new document uploaded, I can not parent vertices to an empty without a hook.. 
The opposite is possible but it's not the goal of the simulation.

Comment: I meant delete the hook modifier and parent the whole cloth object to the empty but I'm still not sure it's what you want